# How to load large applet

Tags: java, jsp, applet, loading

I need some advice on how to load a big applet.

I need to make an instance of JWord text editor to work as an applet, but the editor is about 4 mb.

I'm aware of the java web start solution, but my boss doesn't like it, so I'm stuck with the applet solution.

What I would like to ask you is on how to reduce the user waiting time.
JWord needs about 10 external libraries, so the question here is:

-pack up all in a single big jar?

-make the jars load singularly?

I'm putting this in a jsp page, but the last time I developed an applet the tag "applet" was not deprecated. Now I saw that it's been substituted with "object" tag, can someone help me with that? Point the similarities/differences?

And finally, since this is a big applet, I would like to know if there's the possibility to remove the grey box in the waiting, maybe putting a loading bar in replacement? If so please provide examples! Never done that before..

Thank you

Comment: That is effectively 3 questions.  Which one do you want answered on this thread?

Comment: *"I'm aware of the java web start solution"* Which particular JWS solution are you referring to?  *"but my boss doesn't like it, .."*  Why not?

Comment: Andrew Thompson,the boss wants the application to open a lightbox popup in which I will insert the applet. The text inside the editor is part of a Spring form, so when the user saves the text it will be part of an hidden field in the form. I'm not referring to any particular JWS solution,I just think it can't be done this way. Am I wrong?

Comment: BTW - is it this [JWord text editor](http://www.pilotltd.com/index_en.jsp?pagenum=90004)?  The [demo. page](http://www.pilotltd.com/index_en.jsp?pagenum=90010) shows demos. of 2Mb & 1Mb.  Why is your deployment **4Mb?**  Looking through the JNLP's of the extension shows it uses JGoodies PLAFs.  Nice..

Comment: Yes Andrew, it's that editor. If you download the evaluation package you can see it's 4.44mb zipped. I'm going to strip it down of the components I don't need, such as mathemathical functions, but that's going to happen in the future. Since I'm running short of time I need to put it up and running as is. That's why I wrote "about 4 mb". I'm not familiar with JGoodies PLAFs. Why you say it's nice?

Comment: *"That's why I wrote "about 4 mb"."* It seems the actual client download will be 2Mb or less. *"I'm not familiar with JGoodies PLAFs. Why you say it's nice?"*  Because they are pretty.  But then, I only looked at the extension JNLP & saw 'JGoodies'.  JGoodies is *best* known for their PLAFs, but also make other things like layouts and a data binding API.  It might be one of those that is used in JWord.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In deference to Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, I think 4meg is a huge download for an applet.  Perhaps that is just me talking from the perspective of my very slow wireless connection.  Some people have gone (significantly) further in applet size on LANs with high bandwidth.

### Decrease the size of the download.

Use [Pack200](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/pack200.html)
& obfuscation (one of the few end purposes for which obfuscation is well suited).

### Provide information to the user as applet loads.

#### Before the applet loads

See [Special Attributes of Applets - `image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html#specialattributes).

> **image** The `image` attribute allows you to replace the default animation with a custom graphic.

Use an animated GIF like the one below, to indicate that something is happening.

[image: progress bar]

(Image courtesy of http://www.ajaxload.info/)

#### After a tiny 'splash' applet loads

Trusted?  Loader applet using [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) for the bulk of the download.  Pop a
[`JProgressBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) for the downloads after the initial 'splash applet'.

#### JWS versus standard deployment

You seem to be assuming a 'JWS solution' will result in a free-floating app.  That is not the case since the Plug-In 2 JRE (Sun's 1.6.0_10+).  As mentioned in the [info. page on the applet tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) - visit that page and chase the links for more details.

To use the JWS abilities you might have:

- One jar for compatibility applet (used by a pre Plug-In 2 JRE).  This results in one single HTTP request & a slightly smaller<sup>1</sup> final Jar. (1) Smaller than the total size of a number of Jars.
- Multiple Jars for JWS/Plug-In 2 JRE.  Lazy loading of dependent Jars by the JRE as needed, or programmatically using the [`DownloadService` classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/).

See also the [JWS info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for more information on JWS generally.

### Deploying the applet- `applet` vs. `object`.

Don't hard-code HTML for it, use the `deployJava.js` script referred to in both info. pages linked above.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to study every word you wrote. About the three questions question: I would like to receive help to all of them, since they face different parts of a bigger problem. If you think I should post three different questions just tell me and I will. I thought this would help reduce similar topics.

Comment: Eh.. (shrugs)  Why change it now?  Consider it for future questions.  Of course, note that it was just my opinion, not site policy.  Best of luck with the applet.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with having a large applet, and the dependent jar referred to from the invocation snippet in HTML.

See the applet trail in the Java tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html

Note that there is a limit to the memory available to an applet, and - especially for older Java deployments - this may be too small for your application.  In that case the easiest way is most likely the Java WebStart (which for Java 6 supports Applets too) where you can specify your memory needs.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial. I know there's nothing wrong with a large applet, I'm just trying to fine tune it. Any idea for a loading bar? I didn't know of the memory limit, I'm going to research about that and try to determine how much memory the applet needs to run. As I told to Andrew Thompson I cannot use JWS,read my comment to his. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink your program with the Free and Open Source program [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). It takes big jars, and removes every class which isn't used.